# How to apply textFieldShouldBeginEditing on one specific UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have four text fields for address, city, state, and zip. I need to call a Picker View for the state field only, so I need to hide the keyboard only on the state text field. I'm trying to do this in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing function using this piece of code, but it's applying it to all text fields.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(state: UITextField) -> Bool {
 return false
}
```

I am also applying this piece of code to all text fields so the keyboard will hide on return

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

So all of my text fields are here in the viewDidLoad

```
    address.delegate = self
    city.delegate = self
    zip.delegate = self
    state.delegate = self
```

I hope this is specific enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want a picker view instead of the standard keyboard for a text field, set the text field's `inputView` to the picker view. You don't need to implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the delegate call-back, you can verify the 'textField' with your text-fields.
Ex:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    if textField == address {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
       return false
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, by doing this

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(state: UITextField) -> Bool {
 return false
}
```

you're not "selecting" the textField, you are just naming that variable.

What you should do is to compare that variable to your properties and act depending on that.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
 if(textField == self.state)
  return false
 return true;
}
```

PS. `address`, `city`, etc. are not very good variable names. Sure, you know what they are, but if somebody else is looking at the code it won't be obvious, I would recommend using names like `addressTextField` or even `addressField` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the tip on the variable names!